# HTML5 Canvas lines not drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

As the question suggests, I am trying to draw a line on a HTML5 canvas. I have tested the values and find that it WILL draw a line from 0,0 to 1920,1040 (the size of the client area) but will not for any other values entered. I'm pretty sure that it will be a simple mistake, but I have yet to spot it and really need to move on. Thank you for your help!

Here's the code:

```
        function DrawGrid() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("Grid");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(872, 432);
        context.lineTo(1048, 432);
        context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    }
```

Comment: Where are `CenterX` and `CenterY` defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be something wrong with your `LineStartX` and `LineStartY` variables (Unable to test because you haven't provided `CenterX` and `CenterY`), replacing them with hard coded integers seems to work.

```
DrawGrid();

function DrawGrid() {
   var canvas = document.getElementById("Grid");
   var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //var LineStartX = CenterX - (width / 2);
   // var LineStartY = CenterY - (height / 2);

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(10, 20);
    context.lineTo(100, 20);
    context.strokeStyle = "#FFAACC";
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.stroke();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Mf8C/

Answer (score -1):

I discovered the problem was caused by where I was calling the function.

Comment: Where did you call the function ? what caused your problem ??