# Canvas lines not staying when drawing from another function

Tags: javascript, canvas

I cannot understand why my lines are not drawing.  I'm trying to combine 2 'drawings'.

- A grid (draws perfectly well).
- A couple of other lines (also draw perfectly well).

But when I combine the 2, I lose my lines or they don't 'seem' to get drawn.

*Note that I have 2 functions, each get the context. Again, I can draw one, but not the other (they don't combine on the canvas).  Also, reading another StackOverflow question, which was answered by add a beginPath(), no difference.  And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007850/html5-canvas-lines-not-drawing) is useless.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasId");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
printLogContext(ctx);
console.log(`__________`);

ctx.beginPath();
//drawGrid(ctx, 300, 300);  
drawAxes(ctx);
drawGrid(ctx, 300, 300);

function drawAxes(context) {
  printLogContext(context);
  context.beginPath;
  context.strokeStyle = "000000";
  context.beginPath();

  context.moveTo(0, 150);
  context.lineTo(300, 150);

  context.moveTo(150, 0);
  context.lineTo(150, 300);

  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();

}

function drawGrid(ctx, width, height) {
  var step = 10;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#E5F7F6";
  //resetTransform(ctx);
  for (var row = 0; row < width; row = row + step) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, row);
    ctx.lineTo(width, row);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  for (var col = 0; col < height; col = col + step) {
    ctx.moveTo(col, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(col, height);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function printLogContext(ctx) {
  (ctx) ? console.log(`Have ctx`): console.log(`Don't habe ctx`);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasId" style="border: solid"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is drawing just fine from both functions.

The problem is that the black axis are overwritten by the light blue grid.

If you change the order of the functions you will see the axis as well.

(*you also have to use `#` when defining a color, even black*)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasId");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
printLogContext(ctx);
console.log(`__________`);

drawGrid(ctx, 300, 300);
drawAxes(ctx);

function drawAxes(context) {
  printLogContext(context);
  context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
  context.beginPath();

  context.moveTo(0, 150);
  context.lineTo(300, 150);

  context.moveTo(150, 0);
  context.lineTo(150, 300);

  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();

}

function drawGrid(ctx, width, height) {
  var step = 10;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#E5F7F6";
  //resetTransform(ctx);
  for (var row = 0; row < width; row = row + step) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, row);
    ctx.lineTo(width, row);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  for (var col = 0; col < height; col = col + step) {
    ctx.moveTo(col, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(col, height);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function printLogContext(ctx) {
  (ctx) ? console.log(`Have ctx`): console.log(`Don't habe ctx`);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasId" style="border: solid"></canvas>
```

Comment: God I feel stupid.  If you look, I did try doing it in the correct order.  I commented it out after.  I thought I had that # sign.  Facepalm!  Thanks for your eyes!

Comment: Follow up if you can... Is there a way to have the black lines always there (without using an image or the order it is placed in)?

Comment: @TinklePooplebottham i wouldn't really know as i have only use canvas for simple things. It seems though that wrapping each line (*in the two loops*) in `ctx.beginPath()` and `ctx.closePath()` will allow the axis to show through (*it is partially overwritten*) but i cannot explain why...

Comment: No problem, I have a few ideas in my head and I have to experiment a little with saving/restoring the context.  I appreciate none the less.